Error: MongoDB error Kind: Server selection timeout: No available servers
I am getting this error:
Environment variables loaded from .env Prisma schema loaded from prisma\schema.prisma Datasource "db": MongoDB database "cluster0" at "cluster0.skcypxf.mongodb.net" Error: MongoDB error Kind: Server selection timeout: No available servers. Topology: { Type: ReplicaSetNoPrimary, Set Name: atlas-r6xb85-shard-0, Servers: [ { Address: ac-n5qimbd-shard-00-00.skcypxf.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} }, { Address: ac-n5qimbd-shard-00-01.skcypxf.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} }, { Address: ac-n5qimbd-shard-00-02.skcypxf.mongodb.net:27017, Type: Unknown, Error: Kind: I/O error: received fatal alert: InternalError, labels: {} } ] }, labels: {} 0: schema_core::commands::schema_push::Calculate from at schema-engine\core\src\commands\schema_push.rs:29      1: schema_core::state::SchemaPush at schema-engine\core\src\state.rs:436

Your server is on a dynamic IP address.  You have to update the firewall at MongoDB
